# Implemented Auth guard in angular 6 application. Implementation is not working.

Tags: angular, angular6, auth-guard

Implemented Auth guard in angular 6 application. Implementation is not working.

**Auth Guard**

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
      constructor(public manageAccountService: ManageAccountService, public myRoute: Router) {}
      canActivate(
        next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        this.manageAccountService.getAccounts().subscribe(
          (res) => {
            if (res.d.Status == 0) {
                this.myRoute.navigate([next.url[0].path.toString()]);
              return true;
            }
            else {
              window.location.href = environment.LOGIN_URL;
            }
          }
        );

      return false;
      }
    }
```

**Expected Result**
Redirect to next.url

**Actual Result**
stuck in loop sending `manageAccountService.getAccounts()` request multiple times

Comment: You're returning false always. The return true is inside a callback, which isn't the same at all. Change your return signature to `Observable<boolean>` and rewrite to meet that.

Comment: i have tried to remove false but result is same

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the guard is ran at each lifecycle step. And there is a lot of them.

See it as if the guard was ran at

- `ngOnInit`
- `ngAfterContentInit`
- `ngAfterContentChecked`
- `ngAfterViewInit`
- `ngAfterViewChecked`

(as if, because it is ran at each navigation event, and there is a lot more than that, and it doesn' speak to everyone)

And you're not assigning your subscription to any variable, which means it is making a subscription on every call.

Finally, the signature of an activation guard is

```
boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean>
```

And in your case, you don't return anything (if you don't understand why, look at RxJS documentation).

You should not make HTTP calls for a guard, but if you want to do so, here is the syntax :

```js
canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable < boolean > {
  if (this['get_accounts_called']) { return false; }
  this['get_accounts_called'] = return this.manageAccountService.getAccounts()
    .pipe(map(res => res.d.Status == 0))
}
```

Comment: I'm going to need more information than that. I don't even know what you expect for starters.

Comment: And people, please comment when you downvote. That's common courtesy.

Comment: Ok, first thing i just want to looping

Comment: 2nd thing please don't write wrong code  .pipe(map(res => res.d.Status == 0))

Comment: `I just want to looping` doesn't mean anything (typos appart), and I made a typo, sorry about that, but you can correct it yourself ...

Comment: sorry, as I said, I am stuck in loop. i just wanted to stop looping.

Comment: Okay, this is clear, I edited the code snippet to prevent several HTTP calls

Comment: i am using httpClient @angular/common/http

Comment: Please look at the code snippet I have posted again. See what I added, it will prevent multiple calls.

Comment: Dude's trying to help you Arsalan, should at least take back the negative vote. I don't know if it runs but he's still trying to help you man. Trichetriche, gave you an upvote for trying.